# CDK cross account Event Rule trigger for CodeCommit fails

Tags: python, aws-cdk, aws-event-bridge

I am trying to deploy Dev and Prod environments from a tooling account, and have hit a dead end.

#### Setup

- **Tooling account**: Will host Pipelines and an EventBus to receive notification when CodeCommit is updated.
- **Development account**: Contains CodeCommit repository and an Event Rule to add a notification to the EventBus in the tooling account. Development environment resources will be deployed to this account.
- **Production account**: Production environment resources will be deployed to this account.

I have created the following trust relationships

```bash
# Tooling account
npx cdk bootstrap aws://<ToolingAccount>/us-east-1 --no-bootstrap-customer-key --cloudformation-execution-policies 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess' --verbose --profile <ToolingAccountProfile>

# Development account
npx cdk bootstrap aws://<DevelopmentAccount>/us-east-1 --no-bootstrap-customer-key --cloudformation-execution-policies arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess --trust <ToolingAccount> --profile <ToolingAccountProfile>

# Production account
npx cdk bootstrap aws://<ProductionAccount>/us-east-1 --no-bootstrap-customer-key --cloudformation-execution-policies 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess' --trust <ToolingAccount> --profile <ToolingAccountProfile>
```

I have successfully deployed the infrastructure to both Development and Production environments from my local system. I have also successfully created the EventBus in the tooling account using CDK.

Below stack deploys successfully

```py
class LabDemoInfraCornerStonePipelineStack(Stack):
    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, config: dict, pipeline_type: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)
        if pipeline_type == "Dev":
            infra_event_dev_bus = events.CfnEventBus(
                self, 
                config['DemoInfraDevPipelineEventBusName'],
                name=config['DemoInfraDevPipelineEventBusName']
            )

            events.CfnEventBusPolicy(
                self, 
                "LabDemoInfraDevCodeCommitEventBusPolicy",
                event_bus_name=infra_event_dev_bus.attr_name,
                statement={
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Principal" : {"AWS" : f"arn:aws:iam::{<DevelopmentAccounNo>}:root"},
                    "Action": "events:PutEvents",
                    "Resource": f"arn:aws:events:{self.region}:{self.account}:event-bus/{infra_event_dev_bus.attr_name}"
                },
                statement_id="LabDemoInfraDevCodeCommitEventBusPolicy"
            )
```

using command

```bash
npx cdk deploy InfraCornerStoneLabDemoPipelineStack --profile <ToolingAccountProfile>
```

When I try to deploy the EventRule in the Development account as follows

```py
class InfraToolingLabDemoPipelineStack(Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, config: dict, pipeline_type: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id,  **kwargs)
        if pipeline_type == "Dev":
            events.CfnRule(
                self, 
                config['DemoInfraDevPipelineEventRuleName'],
                description=f"Sends CodeCommit repository events to the Tooling Pipeline Account {config['DemoInfraDevPipelineEventBusName']} event bus.",
                event_bus_name=config['DemoInfraDevPipelineEventBusName'],
                event_pattern= {
                    "detail-type": "CodeCommit Repository State Change",
                    "source": "aws.codecommit",
                    "resources": [f"arn:aws:codecommit:${self.region}:${self.account}:${config['demo_infra_repo']}"]
                },
                state='ENABLED',
                targets=[
                    events.CfnRule.TargetProperty(
                        arn=f"arn:aws:events:{self.region}:{config['tooling_account_no']}:event-bus/{config['DemoInfraDevPipelineEventBusName']}",
                        id=config['DemoInfraDevPipelineEventRuleName']
                    )
                ]
            )
```

using command

```bash
cdk deploy InfraToolingLabDemoPipelineStack --profile <ToolingAccountProfile>
```

Note: The `app.py` file calling the above class, passes the Development Account information as an `env` variable.

I get the following error

> InfraToolingLabDemoPipelineStack/LabDemoInfraDevPipelineEnvtRule (LabDemoInfraDevPipelineEnvtRule) User: arn:aws:sts:::assumed-role/cdk-labdemo-cfn-exec-role--us-east-1/AWSCloudFormation is not authorized to perform: events:PutRule on resource: arn:aws:events:us-east-1::rule/LabDemoInfraDevPipelineEnvtBus/InfraToolingLabDemo-LabDemoInfraDevPipelin-BR1BO7R0FJ3D because no resource-based policy allows the events:PutRule action

But, as you can see above, I have enabled trust relationships appropriately as per documentation.

The `cdk-labarmory-cfn-exec-role-<DevelopmentAccount>-us-east-1` role trust relationship is as follows

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "cloudformation.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

And the permission allows Administrator access

Initially I was running

```bash
# Tooling account
npx cdk bootstrap aws://<ToolingAccount>/us-east-1 --no-bootstrap-customer-key --cloudformation-execution-policies 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess' --verbose --profile <ToolingAccountProfile>

# Development account
npx cdk bootstrap aws://<DevelopmentAccount>/us-east-1 --no-bootstrap-customer-key --cloudformation-execution-policies arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess --trust <ToolingAccount> --profile <DevelopmentAccountProfile>

# Production account
npx cdk bootstrap aws://<ProductionAccount>/us-east-1 --no-bootstrap-customer-key --cloudformation-execution-policies 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess' --trust <ToolingAccount> --profile <ProductionAccountProfile>
```

then I changed it to

```bash
# Tooling account
npx cdk bootstrap aws://<ToolingAccount>/us-east-1 --no-bootstrap-customer-key --cloudformation-execution-policies 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess' --verbose --profile <ToolingAccountProfile>

# Development account
npx cdk bootstrap aws://<DevelopmentAccount>/us-east-1 --no-bootstrap-customer-key --cloudformation-execution-policies arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess --trust <ToolingAccount> --profile <ToolingAccountProfile>

# Production account
npx cdk bootstrap aws://<ProductionAccount>/us-east-1 --no-bootstrap-customer-key --cloudformation-execution-policies 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess' --trust <ToolingAccount> --profile <ToolingAccountProfile>
```

This slightly improved the error.

I have tried to hard code the account numbers.

I have also tried to manually update the EventBus policy to additionally add the the Development account permissions

from

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [{
    "Sid": "LabDemoInfraDevCodeCommitEventBusPolicy",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": 
    {
      "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<DevelopmentAccount>:root"
    },
    "Action": "events:PutEvents",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:events:us-east-1:<ToolingAccount>:event-bus/LabDemoInfraDevPipelineEnvtBus"
  }]
}
```

to

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [{
    "Sid": "LabDemoInfraDevCodeCommitEventBusPolicy",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": [
    {
      "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<DevelopmentAccount>:root"
    },
    {
      "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<ToolingAccount>:root"
    }],
    "Action": "events:PutEvents",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:events:us-east-1:<ToolingAccount>:event-bus/LabDemoInfraDevPipelineEnvtBus"
  }]
}
```

The `--verbose` command shows correct accounts

None of these steps work

Comment: I think, what you were doing earlier is right way. Use the environment's profile while bootstrapping itself. i.e. `cdk bootstrap --profile <env-specific-profile> --trust <tooling-account-id>`

Comment: As the error message says, you need `events:PutRule` action, not just `events:PutEvents`. And yes, you should use the profile of the AWS account being bootstrapped when bootstrapping (it shouldn't work otherwise). I'm curious - why L1 constructs?